# How can I copy files and create a directory in Makefile?

Tags: c, linux, bash, makefile

From Makefile:

Need to copy a file from `../lib` and create a directory from the current `.` named `test`

And another file and create other directory from the current and named `test2`

Have this, but I don't how to do it, I didn't find any useful info from Internet

```makefile
COPY_FILES = $(DIR)../lib/libmy.a $(DIR)/my.h
DIR =
all: $(COPY_FILES)
$(DIR)/libmy.a:
```

Comment: What part of the process does not work? What part are you struggling with? Your target directory `DIR` is declared as empty, and you are also referencing `$(DIR)` before setting/declaring it.

Comment: @Corion dont know how to create a directory and copy a file into the directory I create it from Makefile

Comment: A `Makefile` is mostly just shell commands, so you use `mkdir` to create directories and `cp` to copy files. Maybe also learn about Makefiles from https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/

Comment: Consider editing your question for clarity.

Comment: Get a simple Makefile that works before you try generalizing it with variables.  Just do `all:\n\tmkdir test\ncp ../lib/libmy.a .`.  When you figure out out to invoke that and get it to do what you want, then start worrying about getting the dependencies correct and making it more generic.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my Makefiles I have the following rules:

```
$(BUILD_DIRECTORY)/$(LIBRARY): $(BUILD_DIRECTORY)
    @clang -c $(COMMON_INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARY_COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LIBRARY_SOURCES)
    @ar rcs $(LIBRARY) *.o
    @mv $(LIBRARY) $(BUILD_DIRECTORY)
    @rm -f *.o

$(BUILD_DIRECTORY):
    @mkdir $(BUILD_DIRECTORY)
```

`$(BUILD_DIRECTORY)` is a dependency of `$(BUILD_DIRECTORY)/$(LIBRARY)`.

If you don't want a rule to create the build directory, you can use the following to create the directory:

```
mkdir -p <directory>
```

The `-p` option is to ignore an error if the directory already exists.